# Avoiding too much casting

Tags: c, casting, integer, igraph

I am currently working on a project which involves searching&moving elements in graphs.  I thought the **igraph** package was pretty good for my simple needs, however, as I am a used to working with java, some things aren't clear.

Why, for instance, do the folks who created the igraph package redefine basic elements like integers as 'igraph_integer_t' ?
Is there a way to avoid having to cast everything back to integers every time I call a function of their library, as this makes the code pretty messy?

Comment: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/

Comment: C is not C++; there is never a need to use casts with integer or floating point types.

Answer (score 2):

As one of the igraph authors, I do realise that this is/was a questionable design decision that was made in the very beginning of the project. The initial intention was really to "add a layer of abstraction": we've worked with scientific source code before where the app used `int` everywhere and due to overflow problems, we had to replace every `int` with `long` all across the source code to make the program work with the problem we were presented with. So that's why we have `igraph_integer_t` instead of simply `int` or `long` - if you find that the `igraph_integer_t` data type is too small for your problems, you have to change only one place in the source code.

In retrospect, the above scenario is pretty rare, so it's probably a pretty weak argument. To complicate things further, `igraph_integer_t` is typedef'd to a `double` for fear of cases when the `long` data type isn't enough on all platforms. (One scenario I can think of right now is counting motifs in a large graph - the number of motifs, although being integer, can easily exceed the limits of the `long` data type on older platforms). Since wasn't around the project at that time when the decision about `igraph_integer_t` was made, it might not be the exact reason, this is just what I think might have been. Feel free to ask on the [igraph-help mailing list](http://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/igraph-help) if you are interested in the gory detals. Anyway, I use the C core of igraph directly a lot (since I'm responsible for the Python wrappers), so I can safely say that there is no need for casting betweeen `igraph_integer_t` and other data types except in two cases:

1. When using an `igraph_integer_t` value in `printf`. You either have to cast `igraph_integer_t` to a `long` and use `%ld` in the format string, or don't do any casting and use `%g` in the format string (which implicitly relies on `igraph_integer_t` being a `double`).
2. When indexing an array with an `igraph_integer_t`. You obviously have to cast it to a `long`.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Naming a type "integer" and defining it as a floating point type. As you say that leads to lots of non-obvious failures: not just the array issue, but also complete failure of the `%` operator and misbehavior of the `/` operator. Thanks at least for acknowledging that it was probably a bad idea.

Comment: By the way, +1 for an very informative answer from the source.

Comment: In case anyone is still reading this: `igraph_integer_t` is now typedef'd to an `int` in the source and not to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather nasty practice lots of libraries do for no good reason. Look up the type of `igraph_integer_t`. If it's `int`, which I expect it is, just use `int` everywhere and pretend `igraph_integer_t` does not exist. There's absolutely no need for casts. All integer (and floating point) types convert implicitly in C, and C `typedef` types are not considered distinct from their definitions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible (I don't know this package), but you should be using igraph_integer_t in your own application, or else building a framework around igraph for you to communicate with.

The thing is, if you use the wrong size integer (short vs. long, signed vs. unsigned, etc.) then you may get some really quirky bugs that are hard to find. I would build a framework to interact with igraph that picks the appropriately size int for the library and compiler you are using. I would avoid casting except in this framework where you know it should be safe.

In a nutshell: add a layer of abstraction.

Comment: This is simply a broken practice by the library authors; there is no legitimate excuse. If they need a particular-sized integer type, their API should be using the standard type for that size, e.g. `int32_t`. If they want a "normal" integer size that varies with the platform, that's `int` or `long` and they should be using one of these types.

Comment: @R.. I certainly agree but that doesn't solve the problem at hand if you need to use the library _now_... right?

Comment: It does. Just look in `igraph.h` or whatever it's called, find the definition of `igraph_integer_t` (which I'm 99% sure will simply be `int`), and then go about using `int` as usual.

Comment: @R.. As I said, I don't know the library. But if you've received it in compiled form, it's not the best idea to be changing it. I actually do need to mark one point of disagreement: I don't know the library authors' intentions of making the new type. So they may have wanted a guaranteed fixed-size type, for instance. Perhaps the library is a huge thing and making the changes would be too time-consuming. My point is that you have what the library gave you: work around it or use a different library.

Comment: That's not changing the library. Absolutely no change to any library file, source or header, is necessary. Simply use the right type (`int` or similar) in your own code that interfaces with the library. Just because `foo.h` is full of `foo_integer_t` nonsense doesn't mean you ever have to write `foo_integer_t` in your own code.